# Install Delayed Job Web raise an error when adding route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

How can I add this line in my routes.rb file?

> match "/delayed_job" => DelayedJobWeb, :anchor => false, :via =>
>   [:get]

What is the procedure to install it?

Answer (score 0):

- Add the below line in Gemfile

  ```
  gem 'delayed_job_web'
  ```
- Execute the command from project directory

  ```
  bundle install
  ```
- Add the below line routes.rb

  ```
  match "/delayed_job" => DelayedJobWeb, :anchor => false
  ```
- Start the server

  ```
  rails s
  ```
- Open the URL in browser (localhost) : http://localhost:3000/delayed_job

Comment: it throughs this error when i add this route 
"`require': cannot load such file -- rack/showexceptions (LoadError)"

Comment: You need to complete step 1 and step 2  and then add entry in routes.rb.

Comment: Yes i have completed the first two steps . But now when i install this gem and run the command rails s it throughs the same error. 
""`require': cannot load such file -- rack/showexceptions (LoadError)""

Comment: can you share full back-trace?

Comment: Its working now. there is an issue in my project that i added an extra migration to delayed job thats why it throughs and error. I have install it on an other project so its woring fine. thanks.